# Locating included assemblies in trimmed self-contained deployment

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, self-contained

I'm learning C# and it's related stack and trying to build trimmed self-contained executable. The problem is in that some assemblies are not directly referenced and are implied to be used via Managed Extensibility Framework, thus trimmer doesn't count them as used. I'm including them in scd using `<TrimmerRootAssembly Include="x"/>`), but they are not "visible" to code, even though they are referenced in the project. Here is my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
        <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.*" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Core\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Core.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.DotNet\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.DotNet.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.JVM\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.JVM.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.Toolkit\Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.Toolkit.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.Toolkit` is successfully included in SCD and is accessible by my application:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    Console.WriteLine(Assembly.Load("Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.Toolkit"));
}

// Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.Handler.Toolkit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

But without direct usage of assembly classes / explicit by-name load it doesn't appear neither in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`:

```
Current domain assemblies:
System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
Ayte.Tool.Toolkit.CLI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Console, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Executing assembly references:
System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Console, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
```

How can i get list of all assemblies that are contained within SCD to eagerly load them? Any direct reference by name, class load or anything else breaks the whole MEF concept, so i would like not to do it in any by-hand method.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions would be install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` and use `DependencyContext.Default`. The correct way is:

```
var assemblies = DependencyContext.Default.GetRuntimeAssemblyNames(runtimeIdentifier);
```

I'm not sure how to properly resolve `runtimeIdentifier`, but using non-existing identifier (e.g. `String.Empty`) will fall back to default set of assembly names, which was sufficient for me.

Comment: DependencyContext.Default.GetRuntimeAssemblyNames(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeIdentifier())

Comment: seems like it's not available on .net standard 2.0 =/

Comment: use NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel ... it seems to support .Net Standard Version >= 1.3